# Is it possible to create a method to have a method passed as parameter and be called inside it?

Tags: java, methods

well I'm wondering if it's possible to have a method where another method is passed as a parameter, so the first method can call the method passed in param?

Like for instance:

```
public void goToVisitManagementForm() throws ParseException {
    if (isAuthenticated() && userTypeIs("Patient")) {

         // I could have this whole block just moved to another method?
        Panel newPanel = new Panel("Choose the details for your visit");
        Component visitManagementForm = new VisitManagementForm(userData,
                this);
        newPanel.addComponent(visitManagementForm);
        mainWindow.setMainPanel(newPanel);

    } else {
        authenticate();
    }
}
```

If the code block would be moved to another method and it would be passed as a parameter to this method. How can I achieve that and is this a good practice? Because in this case I have the ifs that I always need to paste in...
What about other aspects of this?

Comment: What is the application feature you intend to offer through this functionality?  [tag:reflection] springs to mind for achieving the stated functionality, but reflection is often the right answer to the wrong question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a [higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) and you cannot do this in Java 7 or below. You can simulate passing functions to other functions through the use of an anonymous class that instantiates some interface the function expects, and then calling the function on that object.

For example, to pass a no-arg function:

```
interface Function {
    void apply();
}

void takesAFunction(Function function) {
    function.apply();
}
```

Then the following code snippet would do what you want:

```
Function myFunction = new Function() {
    @Override
    public void apply() {
        // your code here.
    }
};
takesAFunction(myFunction);
```

As a side note, reflection is extreme overkill for this type of problem.

Comment: So what do Java users usually do to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: @ArturasM As Mark mentioned, that is what the entire latter part of the post is devoted to. Do you have further questions about the answer? If not, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @ArturasM The visitor pattern is used to simulate double dispatch in Java, while the above is for higher order functions in general. The visitor pattern is implemented in a very similar way to above, so yes in a sense it's like the Visitor pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass methods as parameters using [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/index.html).

First, you get a method object from a class:

```
 Class c = MyClass.class;
 Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
 Method m = // choose the method you want
```

Then your function can take a Method object as a parameter:

```
 public void aFunction(MyClass o, Method m);
```

And then inside that function you can invoke the method:

```
 m.invoke(o);
```

This is a very simple example, where the method doesn't take any parameters. It's pretty easy to expand on this example and add the parameters as well.

Comment: So is reflection used often to achieve something for the scenario I mentioned? Or what's the most typical way Java users solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Reflection can be useful, but for your situation, as I understand it, I think it would be way too complex a solution. There are other approaches. The Visitor pattern comes to mind. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it is a very advanced procedure. You need to use the `Method` object. Here is the javadoc on Method:

here is the javadoc:
 
 - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to be able to pass a method as a parameter. There really is no 'smooth' way to do this in Java. In objective C, it is built right into the language, (@selector tag)